# FOS UserBundle how to create own User Repository

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i stack to create my own FOS UserBundle UserRepository.
I guess its not correct extended?

app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/Repository/UserRepository.php:

```
    <?php

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Repository;



/**
 * UserRepository
 */
class UserRepository extends  \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

    // some function


}
```

Thanks for help.
Mike

Comment: Where is straying your `User` model?

Comment: Can u show namespace of `User` model?

Comment: I want to add a function to get user by role. And my idea was to add the function in the userRepository. In my controller i use the FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine UserManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A repository class is optional so FOS does not define a repository. They only have the UserManager that calls the repository for the entity from Doctrine.

You have to change the repository on your entity:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: O.k. - but my point is still the extension. If i use the repository like on the top, it kicks me out of login. I guess the class UserRepository extends XXX is incorrect?

Comment: No, extending \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository is correct.

Comment: You should use in the controller $em->getRepository() instead of UserManager. If you want to use UserManager you'll have to also override it and add a method in the UserManager and in that method call $this->repository->yourMethod()